# печати файла через BAT'ник

Tags: windows, bat

Не могу отправить файл для печати на прямую. Чтобы принтер задействовал штатный шрифт. (Матричный принтер EPSON)
Нашел в интернете решение через lpt шнур

```
Copy %File% LPT1
```

Но у меня LPT нету. Узнал что BAT файл не знает не чего о USB. То есть usb отправить в принтер нельзя. А можно ли отправить через шнур "ethernet"?? Bat'ник его видит?

Comment: Можно "выкрутися" создать сценарий js/vbs, и запустить его на выполнение. В сценарии можно выбрать файл и пункт "печать". Чисто с командной строки - не подскажу.

Comment: я даже с подсказками вряд-ли пойму что к чему)

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/182655/724113

Comment: А чем не нравится уже существующее решение: [send file 2 printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595421/is-it-possible-to-send-a-file-to-a-printer-with-a-batch-file) ?

Comment: @Daemon-5 не помогло

Comment: Проверил - вполне рабочий вариант. Скорее всего, у Вас возникла проблема из-за наличия в списке нескольких принтеров.

Answer (score 1):

На дефолтный принтер выводит текстовые файлы без проблем.

```
@for /f "skip=1 tokens=1*" %%a in ('@wmic printer where ^(default ^= "True"^) get name') do (
@set printer=%%a
@goto nxt
)
:nxt
@print "c:\Directory\text.txt" /D:%printer%
```